# How to get an ID of a specific element that matches a JQuery selector

Tags: jquery

This should be very simple, but I'm blocking on this....

Let's say, for the sake of argument, that we want to prepend() its ID to each element matching class "class_name".  I thought the right way to do it would be something like:

$('.class_name').prepend($(this).attr('id'));

But it does not work.  It looks like $(this) is only usable inside event callabacks.  But how do I get the ID (or any other attribute) of each specific element?

Many thanks!!!

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do here. Prepend is to create new DOM element, not attribute. Do you want to set a new "id" attribute for the matched object? Do you want to add a class which equals to the id of the element?

Comment: It's a contrived example. Let's say I want to prepend that reads "My ID is <id>".  My question is I want to get to the ID of each matched element, when I use a selector that matches multiple elements.  Is this clearer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `.each()`:

```
$('.class_name').each(function(index, element){
    $(element).prepend($(element).attr('id'));
});
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/d8Uj8/

Comment: glad to help you! if you want, you can accept and/or upvote the answer. take a look at the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: Accepted.  Can't vote up 'cause apparently I am not reputable enough :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `each()`:

```
$('.class_name').each(function(){
    var id = this.id;
    $(this).prepend('<span>' + id + '</span>');
});
```

Also, it's better to wrap it in a tag instead of having an unwrapped text node floating around.